# How to accept more than 1 HTML5 pattern on an input?

Tags: regex, html, validation, pattern-matching

I'm working on a form where I have to get book's ISB numbers. ISBN numbers can be 9 or 13 digits long and i would like to check the input with HTML5 pattern, but I've to accept 9 or 13  long numbers both.

How can I write it down with HTML5?

Comment: Is your question about how regex works? Maybe you want to learn regex?

Comment: My question is how to apply 2 patterns on one input element to accept 2 format as valid data.

Comment: And you cannot do that with regex?

Comment: I've tried it in a wrong way. But thanks, it's clear now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the `pattern` attribute you can use regex:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{9}|\d{13}">
```

So this is not specific to HTML5, this is basic regex. `|` means alternatives.

- [The Regex explained](http://regex101.com/r/wL2gG0)
- [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ERZ2/)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern attribute is based on regular expressions. RegEx {} checks for character occurences (in your case 9 and 13).

You can't check for exactly two different (non-adjacent) lengths with one expression and one {} notation.

You would need to write two expressions: the first one checks for 11 characters and the second one for 15 characters. You can chain these two regular expressions with some conditionality. Some [If-else-conditionality](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) exists, but may not be supported by the browsers.

Example: pattern="{9}|{13}"